# Branding Package and Theme not working together

Tags: css, theme, design-manager

I have a custom theme (applied via the "Change the Look" area) on my SharePoint site. I recently installed a branding package that only applies to non-system pages. However, this seems to completely disable the theme on system pages, as well as the non-system ones.

When I re-apply the theme, it overrides the usage of the branding package master page on non-system pages.

I can live with the theme not applying on non-system pages with the custom theme (I'll simply create override styles for the color of the SP components such as the suite bar.) But, it makes little sense to me that I can not still change the theme of system pages.

Does anyone have any idea how I might get both a branding package with non-system master pages and a theme (for system pages) working together? Or, failing that, another way to alter the system page's CSS that will work in parallel with the branding package? Thank you!

Comment: Potentially answering my own question: the simplest solution seems to be to take the data.theme CSS generated by my custom theme, drop it into a new CSS file (with a lot of !important's, as it's loaded before the system one)  and add it as and Alternate CSS URL on the Change Site Master Page area. Elegant? Hardly. Potential for breakage in future SP updates? Sure. So, I'm all ears for better suggestions. But, for now, this gets me where I need to be.

Comment: In which form this custom theme is packaged - is it a WSP design package, a masterpage, a plain CSS-file, an .spcolor-file, or something else?

Comment: It's a WSP branding package